# YQL xpath not robust enough

Tags: python, xpath, yql

Previously working n xpath using python and it is robust to extract data from a webpage. Now I need to use YQL for the same webpage but it is not robust enough.

I want to get is 
1. Last (AUD)
2. Close
3.Close (%)
4. Cumulative Volume
from https://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=TPM.AX
The xpath I use in python are as below:

```
xpath('//td[contains(., "Last")]/strong/text()')
xpath('//td[contains(., "Change")]/strong/text()')[0]
xpath('//td[contains(., "Change (%)")]/strong/text()')
xpath('//td[contains(., "Cumulative Volume")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')
```

part of the html is here

```
<tr>
                <td rowspan="2" class="sic_lastdone">Last (AUD): <strong>6.750</strong></td>
                <td class="sic_change">Change: <strong>-0.080</strong></td>
                <td>High: <strong>6.920</strong></td>
                <td rowspan="2" class="sic_remarks">
                  Remarks: <strong>-</strong>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="sic_change">Change (%): <strong>-1.17</strong></td>
                <td>Low: <strong>6.700</strong></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>

<tr>
                <td>Cumulative Volume (share)</td>
                <td class='sic_volume'>3,100,209</td>
                <td>Cumulative Value</td>
                <td class='sic_value'></td>
              </tr>
```

But when I want to apply in YQL, it did not work. It only work with

```
select * from html where
url="https://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=TPM.AX"
and xpath="//td/strong"
```

It will gets a lot of data. I want a specific data and need to be robust, so that changes of the webpage, my query still working.How to get the YQL xpath that is robust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably avoid building your xpaths according to visible text.

I always build xpath according to tag attributes, since they usually do not change. That makes the xpath result unique and immune to visible text change in the HTML.

For example, "Last (AUD):" value xpath:
`//td[@class="sic_lastdone"]/strong/text()`

Comment: Just figure out the same xpath answer like yours. Thanks. Is attributes tags is rarely changed?

Comment: Yes, they are essentially like IDs. The text might change (multiple languages support site), but the attributes rarely change, since they are not visible